# Transmitting hex code through Arduino Leonardo by USART to device

Tags: arduino, hex, usart

I am trying to send a hex command to a device with an Arduino Leonardo, that also accepts commands through a Bluetooth interface.

Basically I am trying to switch a laser on and off through hex commands transmitted on an Arduino Leonardo, but I am having no luck. If I send the hex codes through the Bluetooth USB interface it works in the current configuration[wiring config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ70v.jpg), but not when I try and push it over the TX pin (I had to use a voltage divider with a 5k6 and 12k Ohm to bring the voltage down from 5V to 3.3V).

The code I am trying is shown below:

```
byte laserON[] = {0xAA,0x00, 0x01, 0xBE, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xC1};
byte laserOFF[] = {0xAA,0x00, 0x01, 0xBE, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0};

void setup() {
 Serial1.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
for(byte i =0;isizeof(laserON);i++)(Serial1.write(laserON[i]));

delay(1000);
Serial1.write(laserON, sizeof(laserON));


for(byte i =0;isizeof(laserOFF);i++)(Serial1.write(laserOFF[i]));
delay(1000);
Serial1.write(laserOFF, sizeof(laserOFF));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`;isizeof(laserON);` isn't any normal C code that I know. You could try and replace it with `i < sizeof(laserON)`, this at least will fix your loop.

`Serial.write(buf, len)` is indeed better and you'll probably want to write `Serial.write(&laserON[0], sizeof(laserON))`

If you want to confirm that the bytes are sent correctly: use a scope or another uart adapter to read back the data you send and confirm if the bytes are the bytes you send. If there are any problems with that then: please update your post.

The [Arduino Leonardo](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/) doesn't have more than [one UART](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega32u4). Your problem with not seeing anything when directly connecting to `pin 1` is:

> On Uno, Nano, Mini, and Mega, pins 0 and 1 are used for communication
>   with the computer. Connecting anything to these pins can interfere
>   with that communication, including causing failed uploads to the
>   board.

The same probably goes for the Leonardo as it fairly similar. You'll have to use another Arduino board or a software UART if you want to communicate with another device. Another options is to use the double SPI or single I2C bus with a UART expander chip such a the [MAX14830](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/MAX14830.html).

No idea why `Serial1` compiles on your platform, maybe your board settings where wrong in the Arduino IDE and the chip is similar enough for it to compile/flash/work. As a debugging measure you could comment out the `Serial` sections and test it and then reverse it by uncommenting `Serial` and commenting `Serial1`.

Comment: Hi Tarick, thank you for the assistance, this morning I did actually update my code to your suggestion. The 'isizeof' part should have been commented out, I think pasting the code here removed the commenting. My code currently looks as follows:

Comment: byte laserON[] = {0xAA,0x00, 0x01, 0xBE, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0xC1};
byte laserOFF[] = {0xAA,0x00, 0x01, 0xBE, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC0};

void setup() {
 Serial1.begin(19200);
 Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {

delay(1000);
Serial1.write(&laserON[0], sizeof(laserON));
Serial.write(&laserON[0], sizeof(laserON));

delay(1000);
Serial1.write(&laserOFF[0], sizeof(laserOFF));
Serial.write(&laserOFF[0], sizeof(laserOFF));
}

Comment: I have connected it to a another uart adaptor, but I am not getting anything on there, which makes me suspect the way I am implementing it on the Leonardo. I am however receiving the correct feedback through the serial monitor of the arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the question is as follows:

Instead of using the aformentioned line of code, Tarick's suggestion works best:
    Serial.write(&laserON[0], sizeof(laserON))

The issue was that the voltage divider did not work as hoped. A 5v to 3.3v logic level converter did the trick.